# How to import/configure the mongodb package in a vue/nuxt application?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, vue.js, nuxt.js

Example below works for NodeJs, but I can't get it to work inside a VUE component or in the middleware. Backend is VUECLI together with NUXT.

```
// Connection test (NodeJs)
const db = require("mongodb").MongoClient;
// import mongodb from "mongodb"
// const db = mongodb.MongoClient
const dbc = new db("mongodb://localhost:27017", {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true
});
dbc.connect(() => {
    console.log("Connection succesfull!")
})
```

The warnings+errors are:

[image]

Does anybody knows how to correctly set this up?

Comment: You really shouldnt be interacting with a database through a vue component, vue is meant to be compiled to client side js/html. It also looks like the package was never installed or was not installed correctly. Make sure it exists inside of your package.json.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. I was in the assumption that with vue cli was already supporting backend code. I will take a look at the different backend options for Vue.js.

Answer (score 0):

You really shouldn't be interacting with a database through a vue component, vue is meant to be compiled to client side js/html.

But to answer your question It also looks like the package was never installed or was not installed correctly. Make sure it exists inside of your package.json

More on why you shouldnt add your database credentials to your vue application: 
everything you write in vue will be available for the end user to see. So if you add your database credentials to your vue component, anyone can see it in production and im sure you dont want that! Vue compiles to plain html/js/css a bunch of backend frameworks like, `.net`, `django`, `flask`, `express` support Vue since it compiles to plain html!

I was at this point too, when I did not understand Vue so its ok.